# Use of Inner Join on Multiple Column Conditions vs using WHere Clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

I have Table which i need to Self-Join( got this by ROW Number and by Partition etc)
 where i am trying to find when the last Visit was and trying to average it in the end

My question is it better to Use Multiple INNER Join Conditions or Use  Where Clause ?

Original Table

RN, AppId, UserId, Datetime,Country

Multiple Inner Join Conditions

```
SELECT TBL0.AppId   , TBL0.UserId, TBL0.Datetime, TBL1.Country  ,
Diff   ( TBL0.Datetime,TBL1.Datetime)    AS TimeSpans
FROM TBL AS TBL0  INNER JOIN TBL AS TBL1   
 ON TBL0.UserXuid == TBL1.UserId  AND TBL0.AppId == TBL1.AppId

 WHERE TBL0.RN -1  == TBL0.RN
```

On Where Clause

```
SELECT TBL0.AppId   , TBL0.UserId, TBL0.Datetime, TBL1.Country  ,
Diff   ( TBL0.Datetime,TBL1.Datetime)    AS TimeSpans
FROM TBL AS TBL0  INNER JOIN TBL AS TBL1   
ON TBL0.UserXuid == TBL1.UserId

WHERE TBL0.RN -1  == TBL0.RN AND TBL0.AppId == TBL1.AppId
```

So which is better , interms of Performance etc

Comment: Is this `MYSQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: ==? I know that syntax doesn't work in SQl server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not see it for yourself? SQL Server has a built-in analysis tool where you can see the detailed execution plan. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx).